# Possible to know whether a DVI-connected monitor is on via software?

Tags: windows-7, display, remote-desktop, dvi

Is it possible to determine via software whether a DVI-connected monitor is currently powered on? (Windows 7)

Comment: What OS? Your options may differ based on that

Comment: Whoops: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can query the monitor status over [DDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to do it?

For example do you just want to know it is on for your own personal needs coz you could easily install Skype aim a webcam at it and use Skype auto answer to video call the computer.